# Conditionally add apt. Open Graph meta data to different pages on WordPress site

Tags: plugins, functions, facebook, open-graph

The **official [Facebook](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/) plugin** does an excellent job of adding appropriate Open Graph meta tags to different pages (Home, Posts, Pages, Archives, etc.) of a WordPress site.

The problem is it does many things without my permission. Is there a way to get the functions responsible for adding Open Graph meta data from the plugin, so that I can add them to my theme's functions.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[`fb-open-graph.php`](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/facebook/trunk/fb-open-graph.php)** (latest version's file) right inside the extracted folder of the plugin is (solely) responsible for adding Open Graph meta data to the header of your site.

Below is how I've modified the code in the file so that it's fit to be added to your theme's functions.php:

```
/* Facebook Open Graph Markup In Header
 * from /facebook/fb-open-graph.php file */

function fb_output_og_protocol( $property, $content ) {
    if ( empty( $property ) || empty( $content ) )
        return;

    // array of property values or structured property
    if ( is_array( $content ) ) {
        foreach( $content as $structured_property => $content_value ) {
            // handle numeric keys from regular arrays
            // account for the special structured property of url which is equivalent to the root tag and sets up the structure
            if ( ! is_string( $structured_property ) || $structured_property === 'url' )
                fb_output_og_protocol( $property, $content_value );
            else
                fb_output_og_protocol( $property . ':' . $structured_property, $content_value );
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "<meta property=\"$property\" content=\"" . esc_attr( $content ) . "\" />\n";
    }
}

/* Add Open Graph protocol markup to <head> */

function fb_add_og_protocol() {
    global $post;

    $meta_tags = array(
        'http://ogp.me/ns#locale' => get_locale(),
        'http://ogp.me/ns#site_name' => get_bloginfo( 'name' ),
        'http://ogp.me/ns#type' => 'website'
    );

    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
        $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns#title'] = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
        $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns#description'] = get_bloginfo( 'description' );
    } else if ( is_single() ) {
        $post_type = get_post_type();
        $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns#type'] = 'article';
        $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns#url'] = apply_filters( 'rel_canonical', get_permalink() );
        if ( post_type_supports( $post_type, 'title' ) )
            $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns#title'] = get_the_title();
        if ( post_type_supports( $post_type, 'excerpt' ) ) {
            // thanks to Angelo Mandato (http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-facebook-plugin-conflicts-with-powerpress?replies=16)
            // Strip and format the wordpress way, but don't apply any other filters which adds junk that ends up getitng stripped back out
            if ( !post_password_required($post) ) {
                // First lets get the post excerpt (shouldn't have any html, but anyone can enter anything...)
                $desc_no_html = $post->post_excerpt;
                if ( !empty($excerpt_no_html) ) {
                    $desc_no_html = strip_shortcodes($desc_no_html); // Strip shortcodes first in case there is HTML inside the shortcode
                    $desc_no_html = wp_strip_all_tags($desc_no_html); // Strip all html
                    $desc_no_html = trim($desc_no_html); // Trim the final string, we may have stripped everything out of the post so this will make the value empty if that's the case
                }

                // Recheck if empty, may be that the strip functions above made excerpt empty, doubhtful but we want to be 100% sure.
                if( empty($desc_no_html) ) {
                    $desc_no_html = $post->post_content; // Start over, this time with the post_content
                    $desc_no_html = strip_shortcodes( $desc_no_html ); // Strip shortcodes first in case there is HTML inside the shortcode
                    $desc_no_html = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $desc_no_html); // Angelo Recommendation, if for some reason ]]> happens to be in the_content, rare but We've seen it happen
                    $desc_no_html = wp_strip_all_tags($desc_no_html);
                    $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 55);
                    $desc_no_html = wp_trim_words( $desc_no_html, $excerpt_length );
                    $desc_no_html = trim($desc_no_html); // Trim the final string, we may have stripped everything out of the post so this will make the value empty if that's the case
                }

                $desc_no_html = str_replace( array( "\r\n", "\r", "\n" ), ' ',$desc_no_html); // I take it Facebook doesn't like new lines?
                $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns#description'] = $desc_no_html;
            }
        }

        $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns/article#published_time'] = get_the_date('c');
        $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns/article#modified_time'] = get_the_modified_date('c');

        if ( post_type_supports( $post_type, 'author' ) && isset( $post->post_author ) )
            $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns/article#author'] = get_author_posts_url( $post->post_author );

        // add the first category as a section. all other categories as tags
        $cat_ids = get_the_category();

        if ( ! empty( $cat_ids ) ) {
            $cat = get_category( $cat_ids[0] );

            if ( ! empty( $cat ) )
                $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns/article#section'] = $cat->name;

            //output the rest of the categories as tags
            unset( $cat_ids[0] );

            if ( ! empty( $cat_ids ) ) {
                $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns/article#tag'] = array();
                foreach( $cat_ids as $cat_id ) {
                    $cat = get_category( $cat_id );
                    $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns/article#tag'][] = $cat->name;
                    unset( $cat );
                }
            }
        }

        // add tags. treat tags as lower priority than multiple categories
        $tags = get_the_tags();

        if ( $tags ) {
            if ( ! array_key_exists( 'http://ogp.me/ns/article#tag', $meta_tags ) )
                $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns/article#tag'] = array();

            foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
                $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns/article#tag'][] = $tag->name;
            }
        }

        // does current post type and the current theme support post thumbnails?
        if ( post_type_supports( $post_type, 'thumbnail' ) && function_exists( 'has_post_thumbnail' ) && has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            list( $post_thumbnail_url, $post_thumbnail_width, $post_thumbnail_height ) = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

            if ( ! empty( $post_thumbnail_url ) ) {
                $image = array( 'url' => $post_thumbnail_url );

                if ( ! empty( $post_thumbnail_width ) )
                    $image['width'] = absint( $post_thumbnail_width );

                if ( ! empty($post_thumbnail_height) )
                    $image['height'] = absint( $post_thumbnail_height );

                $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns#image'] = array( $image );
            }
        }
    }
    else if ( is_author() && isset( $post->post_author ) ) {
        $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns#type'] = 'profile';
        $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns/profile#first_name'] = get_the_author_meta( 'first_name', $post->post_author );
        $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns/profile#last_name'] = get_the_author_meta( 'last_name', $post->post_author );
        if ( is_multi_author() )
            $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns/profile#username'] = get_the_author_meta( 'login', $post->post_author );
    }
    else if ( is_page() ) {
        $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns#type'] = 'article';
        $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns#title'] = get_the_title();
        $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns#url'] = apply_filters( 'rel_canonical', get_permalink() );
    }

    $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns/fb#app_id'] = 'FACEBOOK APP ID HERE';

    $meta_tags = apply_filters( 'fb_meta_tags', $meta_tags, $post );

    foreach ( $meta_tags as $property => $content ) {
        fb_output_og_protocol( $property, $content );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'fb_add_og_protocol' );
```

**Notes:**

- Plugin version used: 1.0.1
- Make sure the original plugin itself is deactivated first.
- Replace `fb_get_locale()` with `get_locale()`
- Remove (LINE 905):

  ```
  $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[...]');
  ```

  And replace (LINE 906):

  ```
  $desc_no_html = wp_trim_words( $desc_no_html, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
  ```

  With this:

  ```
  $desc_no_html = wp_trim_words( $desc_no_html, $excerpt_length );
  ```

  This fixes a bug in the plugin due to which it spurts out encoded HTML in the `og:description` meta tag ([see Stephen Hariss' comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57622/conditionally-add-apt-open-graph-meta-data-to-different-pages-on-wordpress-site/57623#comment74294_57623)).
- Replace this (LINES 151-154):

  ```
  $options = get_option( 'fb_options' );

  if ( ! empty( $options['app_id'] ) )
      $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns/fb#app_id'] = $options['app_id'];
  ```

  With this:

  ```
  $meta_tags['http://ogp.me/ns/fb#app_id'] = 'FACEBOOK APP ID HERE';
  ```

  (replace FACEBOOK APP ID HERE with, well, your app ID — number)
- I still have this plugin installed, **BUT deactivated** so that I can monitor updates from time to time, and make changes if necessary.

Comment: @StephenHarris Any idea what's wrong with the way this plugin pulls the excerpt? It's all messed. Looks like this: `<meta property="http://ogp.me/ns#description" content="Linus Torvalds believes that GitHub is pretty much useless except for code hosting. He therefore only hosts the Linux kernel source code on GitHub, but does not accept pull requests on the service. Linus Torvalds is best&hellip; &lt;a href=&quot;http://whatthenerd.com/web/does-linus-torvalds-who-developed-git-hate-github/&quot;&gt;Continue reading &lt;span class=&quot;meta-nav&quot;&gt;&rarr;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;" />`

Comment: The `excerpt_more` filter is being applied after the content has been stripped of any HTML. When it's printed, it is done so with `esc_attr`. Removing the filter should fix it.